# General Distributive Law and Axiom of Choice

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Where can I find the proof of the fact that general distributive law of union over intersection and intersection over union is equivalent to Axiom of Choice?

The mathematical formulation of the general distributive law of intersections over unions if as follows: Suppose that $\{A_{ij}\mid \langle i,j\rangle\in I\times J\}$ is a family of sets, then: $$\Large\bigcap_{i\in I}\bigcup_{j\in J} A_{ij}=\bigcup_{f\in J^I}\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i\, f(i)}$$

Comment: I've added the formulation of the general distributive law for intersections over unions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don’t know a reference, but I can give you a fairly short proof. (I want it available as a reference for myself, even if you really want only a reference.)

The harder direction is that the general distributive law in question implies $\mathsf{AC}$. I’ll prove $\mathsf{AC}$ in the following form: for any sets $X$ and $Y$, each surjection $f:X\to Y$ has a right inverse.

> **Proof:** Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets, and let $f:X\to Y$ be surjective. For $\langle y,x\rangle\in Y\times X$ let $$A(y,x)=\begin{cases}\{0\},&\text{if } y=f(x)\\0,&\text{otherwise}\;.\end{cases}$$ For each $y\in Y$ there is an $x\in X$ such that $y=f(x)$, so $\bigcup_{x\in X}A(y,x)=\{0\}$, and therefore $$\bigcup_{g\in{^YX}}\bigcap_{y\in Y}A\big(y,g(y)\big)=\bigcap_{y\in Y}\bigcup_{x\in X}A(y,x)=\{0\}\;.$$ Thus, there is a $g\in{^YX}$ such that $$\bigcap_{y\in Y}A\big(y,g(y)\big)=\{0\}\;,$$ i.e., such that $y=f\big(g(y)\big)$ for each $y\in Y$. Clearly $f\circ g=\operatorname{id}_Y$, as desired. $\dashv$.

The other direction is routine. Assume $\mathsf{AC}$. Given sets $A(i,j)$ for $\langle i,j\rangle\in I\times J$, suppose that $x\in\bigcap_{i\in I}\bigcup_{j\in J}A(i,j)$; then $J_x(i)=\{j\in J:x\in A(i,j)\}\ne\varnothing$ for each $i\in I$. Let $\xi:I\to J$ be a choice function for $\{J_x(i):i\in I\}$; then

$$x\in\bigcap_{i\in I}A\big(i,\xi(i)\big)\subseteq\bigcup_{\varphi\in{^IJ}}\bigcap_{i\in I}A\big(i,\varphi(i)\big)\;.$$ On the other hand, if $x\in\bigcup_{\varphi\in{^IJ}}\bigcap_{i\in I}A\big(i,\varphi(i)\big)$, then there is a $\varphi\in{^IJ}$ such that

$$x\in\bigcap_{i\in I}A\big(i,\varphi(i)\big)\subseteq\bigcap_{i\in I}\bigcup_{j\in J}A(i,j)\;.$$

Comment: Please tell me if I am wrong. Suppose I have to obtain AC from $\bigcup_{i\in I}\bigcap_{j\in J} A_{ij}=\bigcap_{f\in J^I}\bigcup_{i\in I}A_{i\, f(i)}$. Then I may use $\bigcup_{y\in Y}\bigcap_{x\in X} A(y,x)=\bigcap_{g\in X^Y}\bigcup_{y \in Y}A(y,g(y))=\bigcup_{h\in (X^Y)^Y}\bigcap_{g\in X^Y} A(g(y),h(g(y)))$. Then, as above we obtain $\bigcap_{g\in X^Y} A(g(y),h(g(y)))=\{0\}$. Now, I can justify myself to claim that there exists $h,g$ such that $y=f(h(g(y)))$.

Comment: Last line is I can not justify.......

Comment: @Steve: In my proof change the definition of the sets $A(y,x)$ by reversing the clauses: $$A(y,x)=\begin{cases}0,&\text{if }y=f(x)\\\{0\},&\text{otherwise}\;.\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

This result was proved in the 50's by the Brazilian mathematician Edison Farah (University of São Paulo). A reference (in Portuguese) is available below:

https://www.ime.usp.br/acervovirtual/textos/brasileiros/farah/algumas_proposicoes_equivalentes_ao_axioma_da_escolha/files/algumas_proposicoes_equivalentes_ao_axioma_da_escolha.pdf?fbclid=IwAR1Qmlgvhsg850bUik1URUJPCRH_zhQo1VcTyt1_c0YHJs5ZlE6MNJZSsh4